# Special character issue in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, special-characters

I'm trying to create a regular expression based on a list of Banned Words.  This will be compared against a string to find the banned words.  No sub-words should be found.

The banned words will also be modified to include other characters that could be substituted to take the place of a letter such as "@" or "!" in viagra; "v!@gra"

So I have a string, I search it for a word.  I then write the regular expression using a word boundary to include all possible other characters.

This works until I come across needing to find a special character.  I realize with word boundaries that it will not find a regular character the same way- but I'm not sure on a good alternative.

Pseudocode:

```
string ReviewText = "$uck";
string BannedWord = "suck";
string regexInput = "";

if (BannedWord .Contains("s") || BannedWord .Contains("S"))
{
    BannedWord = BannedWord .Replace("s", "[$s25]");
    BannedWord = BannedWord .Replace("S", "[$s25]");
}

regexInput = @"\b" + bannedWord + @"\b";
```

That should create `\b[$s25]uck\b`.

I realize that this is bad since it is using a word boundary on a special character- but I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want for all normal characters without it.

Is there a combination of things somehow that I can do in order to fix this issue?  I've tried all I can think of.

Basically I'm trying to create a moderation tool based on a word-list, and generate the regular expression on the fly.  Now I just need it to work in cases of special characters as well.

Comment: Is replacing the special characters with alpha characters up front an option?  ie: ReviewText. Replace("$", "s") and then make your match case-insentive?  You would obviously want to be replacing on a copy of your data.  The issue becomes the number of creative ways people have to replace their letters (ie: /\/ is N while j, !, | and / are all used to replace  i, there are probably others too when you get in to extended ASCII or Unicode).

Comment: This is an AI-Hard problem and I strongly discourage you from trying to solve it by yourself. There is [existing software](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2.122/lib/Regexp/Common/profanity.pm) to try to solve this; start with such a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is there a combination of things somehow that I can do in order to fix this issue?`

Yes ..

Dot-Net can do expression yes/no conditionals.  Using that info you can
still construct your `regexInput` string the same way, just replace the `\b` with the
appropriate conditional.

This way you are free to replace any character in Bannedword to anything else
without ever worrying about boundry conditions.

Example regex string result:

```
 # (?(?=\w)\b|\B)[$s25]uck(?(?<=\w)\b|\B)

 (?(?= \w )  # Conditional, is next letter a word
      \b          # yes, word boundry
   |  \B          # no, not word boundry
 )
 [$s25] uck 

 (?(?<= \w )  # Conditional, was prev letter a word
      \b          # yes, word boundry
   |  \B          # no, not word boundry
 )
```

Just change your Pseudocode to :

```
string ReviewText = "$uck";
string BannedWord = "suck";
string regexInput = "";

if (BannedWord .Contains("s") || BannedWord .Contains("S"))
{
    BannedWord = BannedWord .Replace("s", "[$s25]");
    BannedWord = BannedWord .Replace("S", "[$s25]");
}

regexInput = @"(?(?=\w)\b|\B)" + bannedWord + @"(?(?<=\w)\b|\B)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the number of special characters and sub-phrases is near limitless. Multi-character representations are also problematic.

For example: |-|acking or /iagra

(Doubly difficult because the string lengths don't match)

Also, the requirement that no sub-words should be found, means that you'll not block interesting new phrases as well. For example, calling someone a "pigf**ker" will be every offensive, but not picked up by your algorithm.

The family or complexity of regexes you'll need is going to grow considerably. You may want to think about a primitive (or not so primitive) tokenization / normalization approach. Otherwise, you'll have no chance in catching things like "f * * k".

This type of problem is more art than science, and while you'll be able to help admins, I'm not sure you'll be able to do it all 100% automatically. Be sure to leave room in your project for a reporting system. They're hard to get away from.

Comment: I completely understand, and yes I do know about the multi-character replacement and sub-phrase issues.  That being said I'm trying to stick to the standard I'm being asked to.

That standard is as I stated.  Please let me know if you have any guidance you could give.